# UK pound sign(£) is displaying as Â£ in generated csv file

Tags: java, android, csv

I am trying to generate a CSV file in my application using the code below:

If I open the file in Excel 2007, then I get `Â£` wherever a `£` sign should appear.

```
try {
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);

 fw.append("Item Name");
fw.append(',');

fw.append("Item Sku");
fw.append(',');

fw.append("Tax Rate (%)");
fw.append(',');

fw.append("Item Qty");
fw.append(',');

fw.append("Unit Price (\u20AC)");
fw.append(',');

fw.append("Total Price (\u20AC)");
fw.append(',');

fw.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
 Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName() ,"Error in create CSV File: "+e.getMessage())
}
```

Comment: Do you have any solution? if you have then add your answer please. I have same issue with euro sign. thanks in advance.

Comment: I had same issue in my nodejs app, You may need to use the `"\t"` delimeter, and preappend BOM `'\ufeff'` in your csv string and set the encoding to `'utf16le'` just like I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45232685/5228251 I don't have idea of java so you need to look into how to do this in java. hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You need to use windows-1252 encoding and not the default. This worked for me.