# Node.js generated csv file is displaying Â£ for a UK pound sign (£)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, csv, encoding

I'm using this [json2scv](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv) package parsing my data (sample json data is described in below code)

I am trying to generate a CSV file in my nodejs application using the code below:

If I open the file in Excel, then I get `Â£` wherever a `£` sign should appear.

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var fields = ['car', 'price', 'color'];
var myCars = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": "£40000",
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": "£35000",
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": "£60000",
    "color": "green"
  }
];
var csvStr = json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields, del: ',' });

fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvStr, { encoding: 'utf8' },function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved');
});
```

Any Thoughts ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a text encoding issue. You're saving UTF-8 but at some point this is being read as ISO-8859-1 (or similar). Try adding a BOM at the start of the file, saving in 8859-1, or explicitly specifying the encoding on loading.

Comment: @Richard adding BOM "\ufeff" and using encoding "utf16le" solved the issue. Thanks for your feedback thou.

Answer (score 5):

I have got the solution from this answer and it's question thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975629/5228251

> **UTF-8 Example:**
>
> ```
> fs.writeFile(someFilename, '\ufeff' + html, { encoding: 'utf8' }, function(err) {
>    /* The actual byte order mark written to the file is EF BB BF */
> }
> ```
>
> **UTF-16 Little Endian Example:**
>
> ```
> fs.writeFile(someFilename, '\ufeff' + html, { encoding: 'utf16le' }, function(err) {
>    /* The actual byte order mark written to the file is FF FE */
> }
> ```

After go through above answer and it's thread then I have modified my code like this:

- Changed delimeter option to `"\t"` instead of `","`
- Prepended `"\ufeff"` to the csv string
- Changed encoding to use `"utf16le"`
  instead of `"utf8"`

Here's my updated code:

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var fields = ['car', 'price', 'color'];
var myCars = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": "£40000",
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": "£35000",
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": "£60000",
    "color": "green"
  }
];
var csvStr = json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields, del: '\t' });

fs.writeFile('file.csv', '\ufeff' + csvStr, { encoding: 'utf16le' },function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('file saved');
});
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: <3 This is great! Thank you!

Comment: Answer is valid for all unicode characters issue if they are not displaying better. try above it may help

Answer (score 2):

**in 2022** answer

(using changed), call Parser class from json2csv lib

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

const myCars = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": 40000,
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": 35000,
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": 60000,
    "color": "green"
  }
];

const json2csvParser = new Parser();
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);

console.log(csv);
```

With **delemiter:**

```
const json2csvParser = new Parser({ delimiter: '\t' });
const tsv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);
```

With fields

```
const fields = ['carModel', 'price', 'colors'];
const json2csvParser = new Parser({ fields, transforms });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);
```

More eamples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)

Comment: well said, thanks for contributing !